# How to enable underline access keys for context menu of any window in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, shortcut-keys

Here is how the context menu appears currently on Ubuntu 20.04 when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> on an active window. The items don't have underlined access. So I have to use arrow keys to navigate and press enter.

[image: Ubuntu 20.04 Window context menu not having underlined access keys]

Here is how I want the context menu to appear. Just pressing the underlined character must execute the menu item.

[image: Ubuntu 16.04 Window context menu having underlined access keys]

In my opinion, this is about the changed display manager after Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 16.04 used `lightdm` and from Ubuntu 18.04 it got changed to `gdm`.

Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigating Window Menu via keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971856/navigating-window-menu-via-keyboard)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use window menu accelerators/mnemonics in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032810/how-to-use-window-menu-accelerators-mnemonics-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)